# How do I check to see if there are certain characters in a column in a dataframe for use in an if statement?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, and I want to use the presence of a certain value in any row of a particular column of that dataframe as a logical condition.

Every value in this column is a character. Here are some examples of the data that I have in this column:

Example Row 1:

> ID=AB3, totalServicePrice=25.0, isLeased=true, error=Error
>   [errorId=[CSSM-SOR-306], errorMessage=Unknown Error.]

Example Row 2:

> ID=AB4, totalServicePrice=25.0, isLeased=true, error=null

If the column contains error=Error in any row, I want my if clause to clause to execute, and if it doesn't, I want my else clause to execute. I've tried the following things:

```
if('error=Error' %in% equipmentSubstring3$object.object)

if(equipmentSubstring3$object.object %like% 'error=Error')

if(grepl('error=Error', equipmentSubstring3$object.object)

if(grepl('error=Error', equipmentSubstring3$object.object, fixed=TRUE)
```

The first if clause evaluates to false. The 2nd-4th all also evaluate to false, because each condition that I put inside the if clause returns a list of true and false for every single row in the column, and the if statement only evaluates the first element from that list.

How do I make the if clause evaluate to true if my column contains the value that I'm looking for?

Comment: If you're looking for the string in "any row", use `?any` e.g.: `any(grepl("a", c("aa","b","cc")))` and `any(grepl("a", c("dd","b","cc")))`

Comment: `grepl("error=Error", ColumnOfInterest)` should suffice

Comment: @Onyambu - not really, as that returns TRUE or FALSE for every row, which `if()` can't handle properly.

Comment: @thelatemail the issue is to get true or false in each row of the specified column and do the intended computation. for example if you can have a for loop whereby: `for i in .. if(grepl("error=Error", ColumnOfInterest[i])) do this else do that` or rather use the vectorized `ifelse` incase the length of the returnd vector is same as the input vector and also of the same class

Comment: @Onyambu - "*the issue is to get true or false in each row of the specified column*" - it's not though. OP is asking for "I want to use the presence of a certain value *in any row of a particular column* of that dataframe as a logical condition"

Comment: @thelatemail got it. In that case, `any(grepl("error=Error", ColumnOfInterest))` should work

Comment: thelatemail is spot on. Thanks for the help y’all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me see if I understand, if the column error has the word "Error" in at least one of his rows then you want to run a clause (the condition evaluates to true). This would be my solution:

```
    library(stringr) # Useful for string manipulation
    findingError <- str_detect(pattern = "Error", dataframe$errorcolumn) # This function detects the presence of a pattern within a string

    if(any(findingError)) { #The Any function evaluates to true when at least one of the components of a logical vector is TRUE
    # Do something
    }
```

Comment: This works too, but I don’t want to install any packages that I don’t need on my server so I’m going with thelatemail’s solution. Appreciate the advice though!